# if $B$ is countable, then the following are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Suppose $B \neq \varnothing$. Prove the following are equivalent

${\bf A.}$ B countable

${\bf B.}$ there is a surjection $f: \mathbb{Z}_+ \to B$

${\bf C.}$ there is an injection $g: B \to \mathbb{Z}_+ $

#### Attempt:

(I already proved $A \implies B$) First we prove $B \implies C$. Let $f$ be surjection. Since $B$ is not empty, it has a smallest element, say $b_1$ and $f$ surjection $\implies$ there is some $i_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $f(i_1) = b_1$

Now, consider $B \setminus \{ b_1 \}$. If this set is empty, then $g(b_1) = i_1$ is desired injection.

If not, then there is smallest element in $B \setminus \{b_1\}$, call it $b_2$ and so $\exists i_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ so that $f(i_2) = b_2$

Now, if $B \setminus \{ b_1, b_2\}$ is empty, then $g(b_k) = i_k $ for $k=1,2$

If we continue in this fashion, we obtain a list $\{ b_1,b_2,...... \}$ so that $g(b_k) = i_k $ where $i_1,i_2,.....$ are positive integers.

${\bf C \implies A}$

Take $g: B \to \mathbb{Z}_+$ an injection. We need to prove $B$ is countable.

By contradiction if $B$ is uncountable, then there is ${\bf NO}$ bijection from $B \to \mathbb{Z}_+$ but this really doesnt help, we can still have injections.

My other idea is to procceed as : since $g$ is injection then $g$ maps some $b_i$ from $B$ in one-to-one correspondence to positive integers: $g(b_i) = i$ say $i \leq n$

But I am having trouble seeing how to extend this to a surjection. Any help? Is my first implication correct?

Comment: Do you know the fact that the countable union of countable sets are countable?

Comment: nope, this is literally an exercise right after the definition of countable set

Comment: You can proceed as for before. We have that $B$ is in bijection with $g(B)\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_+$.

Comment: Also there does not need to be a bijection $B$ to $\mathbb{Z}_+$. Consider $B=\{5\}$.

Comment: I fixed it. I didnt mean bijection...

Comment: What is your definition of countable?

Comment: A is countable if it is either finite or countably infinite. And countably infinite if there is a bijection from set to $\mathbb{Z}_+$

Comment: For $B\implies C,$ let $g(b)=\min f^{-1}\{b\}=\min \{n\in \Bbb Z_+: f(n)=b\}$ for each $b\in B$.....Now $ g$ is injective because $f(g(b))=b$ for all $b\in B$ so if $g(b)=g(b')$ then $b=f(g(b))=f(g(b'))=b'.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C is usually the definition of countable.
To finish the proof prove
exists injection f:X -> Y iff exists surjection g:Y -> X.

Left to right.  Let g(y) = f$^{-1}$(y) for all y in f(X)
and for all y not in f(X), g(y) any element of X.

Conversely define for all x in X, 
f(x) to be some element in g$^{-1}$(x).

Comment: Doesn't this property require AC?

Comment: Yes.  But so what? @Lazarus

Comment: Well since some people do not seem to accept it, I thought it'd be great if there would be a proof that does not require AC.

Comment: I'm a pro-choice mathematician.  Are you not pro-choice? @Lazarus.